# Exact conditions under which the arithmetic progression $\{bk + r\}_{\{k\in\mathbb{N}\}}$ contains 0,1, or 2 primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $p$ is prime, and $p|b$ and $p|r$, where $0\leq r<b$.

Here's what I've tried:

If $r|b$, then $r\neq 1$ (since otherwise $p=1$, a contradiction), so $bk+r = (cr)k+r$ for some integer $c$, so $bk+r = r(ck+1)$ so that if $r|b$, there cannot be any primes.

I'm thinking of maybe using the division theorem to figure out if $r$ does not divide $b$ but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: You may wish to have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write math here. Also, what do you mean by $\{bk + r\}$?

Comment: I mean the progression {bk+r}. For example, for b=4 and r=3, the progression 4(0)+3, 4(1)+3,....

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You know $p \mid b$ and $p \mid r$, so if $k$ is an integer, $p \mid bk + r$.
So, what prime could $bk+r$ possibly be?  And what would $k$ have to be to make it be that prime?

Comment: Since we want a prime dividing another prime, they have to be equal, so bk+r = p, so k = (p-r)/b.

Comment: How does this tell me there are 1 vs. 2 primes though?

Comment: You just said the prime has to be $p$.  That's one, not two.  The real question is whether it is $0$ primes or $1$ prime.